# Magento 2: Load customers by customer group

Tags: magento2, customer

How to load all customers by a specific customer group in magento 2?

Comment: do know the group id of customers you want to load?

Comment: yes i know group id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it as by below.

```
$customer = $this->customer->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groupId);
```